# iTextSharp pdf table cell height issue

Tags: layout, pdf-generation, itext

I have iTextSharp 5.4.4 (nuget) and have a nice table with a barcode (ean13) and text below it.
I have specific tablecell heights (and cell widths) because I want to print the pdf to an A4 with stickers.
Here is the current layout:

[image]

as you can see, there is a rather large gap between the ean13 code and the text below.
here is my C# code:

```
PdfPCell c = new PdfPCell();
c.FixedHeight = 21.2f * postScriptPointsPerMilimeter; // to get to accurate milimeters
c.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
p.Font.Size = 6;
Chunk code = new Chunk(dr["productcode"].ToString());
p.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
p.Add(code);

BarcodeEAN ean13 = new BarcodeEAN();
ean13.CodeType = BarcodeEAN.EAN13;
ean13.Code = dr["ProductEan13"].ToString();
ean13.BarHeight = 4.0f * postScriptPointsPerMilimeter;
var a = ean13.CreateImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null);
a.ScalePercent(90);

c.AddElement(a);
c.AddElement(p);

t.AddCell(c);
```

My question is to reduce the space between the barcode and the text. I cannot see if it has something to do with the barcode's margins or the paragraph's or maybe both... hard to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
p.Leading = 0;
```

That was missing. I thought that

```
p.SpacingBefore = 0;
```

would do the trick, but it didn't. `Leading` did!